# How do I switch on Device Encryption under Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Home does not include support for BitLocker, but is reported to support a feature called Device Encryption to provide full disk encryption, however I can't find any way to enable it.

If I search for "device encryption" in the Start menu, I get an option for "Device Encryption", but when I click it I get only a Settings window with empty search results.

[image: searching for encryption]

[image: what happens when I click it]

I've enabled signing in with a Windows account, as I believe that's a prerequisite, but still no success.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how I can find out? A Google search for "Windows 10 Device Encryption" yields nothing helpful.

Comment: "Device encryption is available in all Windows RT 8.1 PCs, and in Windows 8.1 *PCs that support InstantGo*. InstantGo allows your PC to wake up instantly from sleep with your apps and data up to date. For more details about whether you can use device encryption with your PC, check the info that came with your PC or go to the manufacturer's website." [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/using-device-encryption)

Comment: Frankly it's terrible UX that the result appears in search results, but when clicking on it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Device encryption requires device support of a **TPM 2.0 chipset** and **InstantGo**.

Further details can be found via Microsoft's Windows 10 Specifications: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

Comment: See also: [How to find out whether a PC has a TPM chip installed](http://superuser.com/q/235228/90668)

Answer (score 2):

If your device does support TPM and InstantGo (Connected Standby), you can enable the option on the Modern UI System, About screen.

Scroll down on the right hand side pane, and there's a section for Device Encryption.

An additional limitation is that in Windows 10 Home (which most of the smaller tablets that have InstantGo have) you can't enable drive encryption's PIN security (which requires gpedit), so whilst the drive is encrypted, it doesn't prevent anyone starting the device and just getting in if you either have a missing or weak windows login.